# If $F(x) = \int_0^x e^{\sin(t)} dt$ , so $F'(0)$ is equal to:

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

> If $F(x) = \int_0^x e^{\sin(t)} dt$ , so $F'(0)$ is equal to:

(A) $-2$  $\quad$  (B) $-1$  $\quad$  (C)  $0$  $\quad$  **(D)  $\mathbf1$**  $\quad$  (E)  $2$

**My attempt**:

$$\frac{d}{dt}F(x) = \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^x e^{\sin(t)} dt\Rightarrow F'(x) = \int_0^x \frac{d}{dt}e^{\sin(t)} dt$$

$$F'(x) = e^{\sin(t)}|_{0}^{x} = e^{x} - 1 \implies F'(0) = e^0-1 = 0$$

(wrong answer)

Where am I missing?

Comment: How does $\sin(t)|_{t=x}$ become $x$? Also, I'm not so sure about the lower limit thing. Doesn't that disappear under differentiation?

Comment: Remember the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/

Comment: I've done some mistakes about the derivative and i realized it but the expression became more difficult to me. $F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x e^{sint} dt =  \int_0^x \frac{d}{dt} e^{sint}.\frac{dt}{dx}dt$

Comment: Check that link.There's a problem with your formula.

Comment: You need to multiply the derivative of the integral i.e the function itself with the derivative of their limits which gives $ (e^0)(1)-(1)(0) = 1$

Answer (score 3):

When you have $g(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$ then $g'(x) = \frac{\delta g}{\delta x} = (\int_0^xf(t)dt)^{'}=  f(x)$

So in your function:
$$F'(x) = e^{sin(x)}$$ and for x = 0:
$$F'(0) = e^{sin(0)} = e^0 = 1$$

That's completely different from $g(x)=\int f(x)dx$ where $g'(x) = f(x)$. That's your mistake in your approach of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The variable in the function

$F(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{\sin t} \; dt \tag 1$

is $x$, not $t$; the variable "$t$" is "integrated out"; we could just as well have written

$F(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{\sin s} \; ds,  \tag 2$

or used any other variable (besides $x$) under the integral sign.

Therefore,

$F'(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{\sin t} \; dt = e^{\sin x} \tag 3$

by the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus); evaluating at $x = 0$ yields

$F'(0) = e^{\sin 0} = e^0 = 1; \tag 4$

the correct answer is thus ***(D)***.

Comment: @AndrewLi:  yes, thank you.  Corrected.  That's what I get for answering before coffee!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We have $(\int_0^xf)'=f(x)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but you applied the rule for integration 
$$\int_a^bf=F(b) -F(a) $$
where $F'=f$.